# Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.MicrofeedException. Internal error code: 28 SharePoint MySite

Tags: sharepoint-online, mysite

One of our users got this error when he tried to post something on his newsfeed

Error Message :

"Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.MicrofeedException. Internal error code: 28. Contact your system administrator for help in resolving this problem"

Thanks,
Sachin Shinde

Answer (score 1):

I've seen error code 28 when the site the microblog is on has exceeded its storage quota. Try increasing the quota to see if that solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This error pops up when your limit for your mysite is reached. Empty your recycle bin to free up some space